# Paypal New Layout Not Return Transaction ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

Old Layout

[image]

New layout

[image]

Paypal payment preview get's me some time old layout and sometime new layout firstly how it is possible with same code.

I don't care which layout was display but old layout return's a transaction id and all data but new layout doesn't get me.

how to fix this error.

Comment: i hv no idea in live but this issue in sandbox @qwertzman